# Excluding values based on countif functions and if statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, countif

I may have an easy question for some of you, but so far it has vexed me thoroughly.  I'm trying to pull data out of a worksheet based on *Facility Name* and *Month* for a particular set of *Procedure Classes* for my Hospital's inter-facility transfer report.  So something like this:
`=IF(COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2)=0, "", COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2))`

Now my issue is this formula counts **ALL** transfers from the hospital being referenced (the $A reference is the month, the B$ reference is the facility name).  I have to exclude 3 *Procedure Classes* from the overall count.  The classes are as follows:

> Ablation/EPS, Advanced Heart Failure/Transplant, Caths/Cath Possible,
>   CTS, General Medicine/Cardiac Eval, Hem/Onc,
>   **Maternal Fetal Medicine**, Neurology, Neurosurgery,
>   **Obstetrics**,
>   **OB/GYN**, PCTA/PCI/Stent, Renal Transplant, Stroke, Surgery (General/Onc), Trauma, Vascular Surgery, "" (Blanks).

The values to be excluded are in bold.  I've come up with a wall of text and I can't figure out if there's a better way to do it.  Additionally, my wall isn't working, it's giving me a #NAME? error.  Any suggestions/direction/insight into where I screwed up would be a great help!

Here's the function:

`=IF((COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Ablation/EPS") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Advanced Heart Failure/Transplant") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, “Caths/Cath Possible”) + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "CTS") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "General Medicine/Cardiac Eval") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Hem/Onc") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Neurology") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Neurosurgery") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "PCTA/PCI/Stent") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Renal Transplant") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Stroke") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Surgery (General/Onc)") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Trauma") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Vascular Surgery") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, ""))=0, “”, (COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Ablation/EPS") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Advanced Heart Failure/Transplant") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, “Caths/Cath Possible”) + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "CTS") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "General Medicine/Cardiac Eval") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Hem/Onc") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Neurology") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Neurosurgery") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "PCTA/PCI/Stent") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Renal Transplant") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Stroke") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Surgery (General/Onc)") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Trauma") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, "Vascular Surgery") + COUNTIFS('Source Data 2016'!$F:$F, B$1,'Source Data 2016'!$I:$I, $A2, 'Source Data 2016'!$H:$H, ""))`

Comment: Wow, what a monster. I'm guessing I could do that pretty quickly with an **array formula** if you provided an anonymized (shortened) version of *Source Data* and a mockup of how your *Ideal Result* would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just do the total minus those 3?  Also, try using `=IFERROR(1/(1/[Formula]),"")` so you don't have to write things twice.  So something like

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(COUNTIFS([area1],[cond1],[area2],[cond2])-COUNTIFS([area1],[cond1],[area2],[cond2],[cond3],[excl1]) -COUNTIFS([area1],[cond1],[area2],[cond2],[area3],excl2) -COUNTIFS([area1],[cond1],[area2],[cond2],[area3],excl3)),"")
```

Or if you make a list of the exclusions, like `exclusions`, and array enter `(CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER)`

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/(COUNTIFS([area1],[cond1],[area2],[cond2])-SUM(COUNTIFS([area1],[cond1],[area2],[cond2],[area3],exclusions))),"")
```

Comment: wow... you're so right.  I'm gonna try this, give me a second and I'll let you know if it works!  I didn't even think of starting from the end product and subtracting! xD

Comment: YEP!  See, this is why I love StackOverflow.  I spent the better part of an hour trying to troubleshoot that monstrosity and within 5 minutes someone comes along, gives me a reality check, and reminds me that sometimes the simplest solution is the least obvious! :)  This totally worked and didn't take any time at all!!  Thanks dashnick!